# Getting same UIImageView onto two differant class screens (iOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, camera

I'm working on an iOS app and have had some trouble with getting photos from the user's photo gallery.

What I need help with doing is getting it so that the user chooses a photo from their photo gallery, and then on the next screen the photo is displayed in an UIImageView.

Unfortunately, while I can do this on one screen, I am having trouble with getting it to work on multiple ones.

I've been trying to import the class files from the first screen into the second but it doesn't seem to do much.

I'm getting user photos through a similar method to [this tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/use-camera-and-photo-library-in-iphone/) (though slightly differant).

I'm fairly new to objective-c, so no doubt I've made some huge mistake somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the selected image from the second view to the first view. Then set the image to the UIImageView declared in first view.

The best way to pass the selected image is 'delegate' method. Declare a protocol. Implement that in first view. Set the delegate to the second view. So whenever an image is selected in second view, pass that to first view thru delegate method.

Comment: I've been having trouble doing this as I'm confused about how I would do this with an image, I could easily do it with something like a NSString, but how would I do it with an image?

Comment: Since UIImage and NSString are objects and inheriting NSObject, both should be treated similar in this case.